# Cannot set tabindex on ASP:LinkButton

Tags: asp.net, asplinkbutton

I have an ASP Web Forms project with a LinkButton control. I try to set the tabindex in the control's property grid and it adds it to the code, however when I compile and run the page the tabindex is gone. The reason I need a tabindex (tabindex="0") is to make this linkbutton tabbable.

I also tried with tabindex 1 and tabindex 2.

Here is my .ascx control:

```html
<asp:LinkButton
    runat="server"
    CssClass="continue-button"
    ID="continue"
    OnClientClick="ProcessFormAnimation();"
    OnCommand="continue_Command"
    TabIndex="2">
    Continue
</asp:LinkButton>
```

Here is the rendered code:

```html
<a onclick="ProcessFormAnimation();" id="continue" class="continue-button">
 Continue
</a>
```

Comment: What is the resulting ASP markup?  What is the resulting HTML in the browser?

Comment: Thanks, @David I added the markup above.

Answer (score 0):

The LinkButton Support TabIndex

[Documentation Microsoft ASP.NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.tabindex(v=vs.110).aspx)

Remembering that,

Only controls with a tab index other than zero will render the tabindex attribute.

Comment: I set the tabindex to 1 and 2 but it still doesn't render.

Comment: see: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17952/Using-a-TabIndex-with-a-UserControl-containing-NET